# Sort objects inner array and return object

Tags: javascript

If I have a object like this:

```
const foo = {
    title: 'Bar',
    numbers: [1, 4, 3, 2],
}
```

I would like to sort `foo.numbers` and return the new foo object.

To sort the array is easy `foo.numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)`

but this returns just the array.

Is there anyway to return the parent object?

for example:

```
const newFoo = sortFooNumbers(foo);

console.log(newFoo);
---
{
    title: 'Bar',
    numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you probably need to clone the object too:

```
const foo = {
  title: 'Bar',
  numbers: [1, 4, 3, 2],
};

function sortFoo(foo){
  const cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo));
  cloned.numbers.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
  return cloned;
}

const newFoo = sortFoo(foo);
```

Comment: Oh I forgot about `Object.assign({}, foo}` This is great! Thanks

Comment: But this is just a shallow copy. Both `foo.numbers` and `newFoo.numbers` are the same array. You need to use `cloned.numbers = cloned.numbers.slice();` before sorting if you want two totally different objects.

Comment: @chris glad to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
const foo = {
    title: 'Bar',
    numbers: [1, 4, 3, 2],
}

function sortfoo(obj){
    obj.numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    return obj
}

sortfoo(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.numbers = foo.numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)
```

You now have an updated `foo` with the sorted array. I'm assuming this is what you want.

Comment: sort is destructive, so there is no need to reassign to itself. `foo.numbers.sort(...); return foo;` would work